# C# and SQL Server - using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I have three columns

```
Fraquence int   
[Prochain étalonnag] date    
[date étalonnage] type:date
```

In Visual Studio, I have a form for adding a new (etalonnage) to my table the user inputs two vules (`Fraquence` and `date étalonnage`).

I want to do this with a stored procedure in SQL Server :

```
Prochain étalonnag = date étalonnage + (Month Fraquence).
```

The column `Prochain étalonnage` will be filled automatically when the user click in button `Add`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide sample code - for more information, read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I know this method  System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths().ToShortDateString(); but i don't want to ues date of today and i don't know how i ues in this exemple

Answer (score 0):

Please check following .NET code, sorry it is in VB.NET
But it is not a problem to convert it to C#

The stored procedure in database is named prAddRow for this sample
It accepts two parameters @p_int and @p_date

```
Dim sqlConnBuilder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
sqlConnBuilder.DataSource = txtSQLServer.Text
sqlConnBuilder.InitialCatalog = txtDatabase.Text
sqlConnBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = True

conn = New SqlConnection(sqlConnBuilder.ToString)

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("prAddRow")
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_int", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date.Now.Date

conn.Open()
cmd.Connection = conn
Dim numberOfAffectedRows As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

The T-SQL source codes for the sample stored procedure is as follows

```
create procedure prAddRow(
    @p_int int,
    @p_date date
)
as
insert into etalonnage (Fraquence , [date etalonnage] ) values (@p_int, @p_date)
go
```

Note: I renamed stored procedure according to marc's note from sp_addRow to prAddRow

I hope it is useful for you

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thank you for warning and information about naming stored procedures

Comment: Another side note: Use `DateTime.Today` or `Date.Today` instead of `.Now.Date`

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERTNEW", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter [] par = new SqlParameter[4];
        par[0] = new SqlParameter("@COD", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        par[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
        par[1] = new SqlParameter("@FERQ", SqlDbType.Int);
        par[1].Value = numericUpDown1.TextAlign;
        par[2] = new SqlParameter("@DATE_ET", SqlDbType.Date);
        par[2].Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        par[3] = new SqlParameter("@DATE_PROC", SqlDbType.Date);
        DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text);
        int k =Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.TextAlign);
        string r = d1.AddMonths(k).ToShortDateString();
        par[3].Value = r ;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(par);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("good add");
    }
```

this is work thanks all

Comment: The value of a date parameter should be a `DateTime` value, not a string. With a string you might get issues that it is not considered to be a valid date (for instance when you publish this to a server that uses a different Culture).

Comment: But  i'm use DateTimePicker so user always give value form Date